# Render content if on index route React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using react router and currently trying to render some content only if I'm on the index route `"/"` and other content for anything else than that.

This is what I came up with so far, no errors show up, but it doesn't seem to play well with the code.

```
var renderContent = function() {
    return (
        <div className="contain">
            {this.props.sidebar}
            <div className="page">
                {this.props.main}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

var renderHomepage = function() {
    return (
         <div className="homepage">
             {this.props.main}
         </div>
    );
}

var toRender = function() {
    if (this.props.path == '/') {
        {this.renderHomepage()}
    } else {
        {this.renderContent()}
    }
}
```

then beneath that I continue with:

```
export default React.createClass({
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <div className="main-content">
         {toRender}
 ...
```

Nothing seems to render at all on any route. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
...

import Home from './Home'

module.exports = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="design" component={{main: deMain, header: deHeader, sidebar: sbAnimations}}>
           <Route path="scheme" component={deScheme}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
)
```

where my `Home` component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hero">
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: How about some route definitions? Could you please include those too?

Comment: Edited them into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You're `renderContent`, `renderHomepage`, and `toRender` are defined *outside* of your class and don't have access to this.props.path. Those will need to be defined inside of your class. like this:

```
export default React.createClass({
renderContent() {
    ...
}
renderHomepage() {
    ...
}
toRender() {
    if (this.props.path == '/') {
        return this.renderHomepage();
    } else {
        return this.renderContent();
    }
}
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <div className="main-content">
         {this.toRender()}
 ...
```

Putting your render functions inside `React.createClass` should work. And your toRender function needed to be updated to return the functions. And you need to execute this.toRender

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean, but I get an error here: `super() outside of class constructor`

Comment: oh shoot i messed up

Comment: i just blindly copied and pasted and figured you were extending `React.Component` but you are using `createClass` removing the constructor function should work

Comment: Yeah I figured so! However, now there are no errors, but I'm getting nothing from the `toRender()` function. Even when it looks like
`toRender() {
 {this.renderHomepage()}
},`

But if I put `{this.renderHomepage()}` instead of `{this.toRender()}`, that renders correctly.

Comment: Oh it looks like you need to update your toRender function to return the other render functions instead of just execute them. updated the code in my answer. Oh and you need to execute this.toRender in the render

Comment: Aha. Didnt know you return functions like that... Sorry, kind of new to React and all. But anyway, that's working absolutely great, thank you so much for your help! Just a note that I changed `this.props.path == '/'` to `this.props.main == null` so that I dont depend on the path.